# Considering local module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite:0

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform

pubspec.yaml

```
name: planner_piyon
description: 
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter



cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
     sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  #mysql1: ^0.20.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.6
  material_design_icons_flutter: ^6.0.7096
  google_fonts: ^3.0.1
  date_format: ^2.0.7
  calendar_date_picker2: ^0.3.6
  firebase_auth: ^4.2.5
  google_sign_in: ^5.1.3
  provider: ^6.0.5
  firebase_core: ^2.4.1
  cloud_firestore: ^4.3.1

flutter:
 uses-material-design: true

 assets:
   - lib/files/

 fonts:
   - family: Bahnschrift
     fonts:
       - asset: lib/fonts/Bahnschrift.ttf
```

'''

'''

```
enter code here


import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';


time_now() {
   return DateTime(
      DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day);
}

save_user_data_to_firebase(username,id,mail,password){
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('user_data');
users.add({
    'name':'$username',
    'id':'$id',
    'mail':'$mail',
    'password':'$password',
    'date':'${time_now()}',
  });
}
```

''''

I didn't have any problems with other firebase features like google login but firestore is not working

what i have tried before
-update google services
-install with cli
-update all modules

thats my warning picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcUBc.png)